# Edit clob data in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-19.2

I have to show oracle database table data in oracle apex interactive report. This table has a clob column(mime type: text/plain).

I am able to successfully display clob data in oracle apex interactive report as guided in below post
https://www.foxinfotech.in/2019/12/displaying-clob-contents-in-oracle-apex.html

Now, I should be able to edit clob column data and save the updated clob data back to database. But I am unable to do this.

Can some one help with this?

Comment: There are a couple of plugins available for this - you could try this: https://github.com/OraOpenSource/apex-plugin-clob-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is to View and Edit a CLOB Content.
This can be achieved by using AJAX in Oracle APEX.
I have created a Blog Post for the above requirement. Please use the link below:
https://akilramesh.blogspot.com/2021/06/display-and-edit-clob-content-in-oracle.html

**Demo:** https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/workspace_akil/r/demo/show-and-edit-clob

Comment: I will definitely try this. Thanks for the solution. However, does this solution work even when clob size is >32767 characters?

Comment: Yes, It will. Please see the demo. I have used > 32767 characters

Comment: Thanks Akil. Its working for >32767 chars. Is there any way I can increase 'region' width and height in page6 (referring to your  example, and where we will be showing clob content). Should I need to tweek region's template? Can you guide me please?

Comment: In the Modal page attributes, there is a section "Dialog". You have the option to specify the Width and Height of the Modal Page there.

Comment: It worked. Thank you Akil. I have few more requirements. Will try from my end. Will come back if I am unable to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233611/discussion-between-akil-ramesh-and-user661981).